# Winforms C# .Add() to sql database is VERY slow

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Application written in C#.  One form is a data entry form, with a save button.

Upon Clicking the Save Button, the code first converts all textboxes to Caps.  Then it declares all the variables for the SQL table fields - to the identifying text boxes

ex (there are several of these types of binds)

```
var vlast = textBox_V_lname.Text;
```

All of this works super fast, as expected (I have used break points to find the hold up).  And here, everything hangs.  It hangs for about 30 seconds (that's a long long time, when you only have 900 records in the table).

```
var badger_History = new Badger_History() { v_noaccess_flag = myacess, v_lastname = vlast, v_firstname = vfirst, v_child = vchild, v_company = vcompany, v_issue_date = vdate, v_location = mylocation, comments = mycomments, h_lastname = hlast, h_firstname = hfirst, h_middle_init = hmiddle, h_title = htitle, h_phone = hphone, h_org = horg, h_work_location = hlocation, pass_type = type, pending_flag = pending };
            oBadger_History.Add(badger_History);
```

It hangs right here:  oBadger_History.Add(badger_History);

badger_History being the model for the table insert. I can post the model itself, but that looks pretty normal.

I have certainly tried manually adding a record with SQL Manager, and that worked instantly, as expected.

I can't figure out what is causing the hang. When I hover over the 'oBadger_History.Add' and go to Definition, all I see is this line

```
public virtual void Add(EntityType entity);
```

Note:  this is an application another staff member developed and has since retired.  I usually don't work with Winforms applications and so - I am in over my head here.

Any insight or nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

I can add as much more code as needed - just wasn't sure if it was necessary to post more

Comment: What ORM are you using. What is SQL Manager

Comment: you need to find all instances of that `Add` method as it is being overridden by a derived class.   Unfortunately you did not show enough for us to point you where to look or really help. `public virtual void Add(EntityType entity);` should have a class associated with it.

Comment: is the list you're adding to just a list or is it an actual dbcontext? how many records are in that list? the more records in the list the slower the insert. use a fresh dbcontext if possible every time

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using the `Add` method, use the `AddRange` method. The latter is internally calculated based on dichotomy, and its performance is n * log (n), which is better than the former n * n.

Comment: What does "The latter is internally calculated based on dichotomy" mean? I know what `dichotomy` means: "a division or contrast between two things that are or are represented as being opposed or entirely different". I don't see how that applies.

Comment: And what do you mean by `its performance is n * log (n), which is better than the former n * n`?

Comment: And do we know that the OP's model has a `AddRange` method?

Comment: oBadger_ Is history a list? If so, there will be an addrange method.

Comment: It's not a `List<>`. The OP makes that clear with the signature `public virtual void Add(EntityType entity);`.